# What is the cost to store luggage in Ho Chi Minh airport (Vietnam)?

Tags: luggage-storage, sgn

I would like to store a bag for up to a month in Ho Chi Minh while I travel. I have read everywhere that there is a storage facility in the airport, but most blogs and forums say that the price is like $1 per hour per bag, and they don't mention the price for long term storage.

Now I have found this photo [here](http://www.vietnam720.info/blogs/2012/9/20/luggage-storage-saigon-hcmc.html) and when I zoom in I can read **420 000 VND** ($12) for storage over 24 hours.

[image: storage]

However does that mean that it's per day, or it's just $12 in total?

I don't care paying a little (maybe up to $100), but I don't want to end up having to pay $12*30=$360 while I could find another solution.

Comment: As a follow up years after the trip, the hotel stored my bag for free (I stayed in the same hotel on both occasions). No problems. It was a mid-range hotel, not the cheapest one, not very expensive either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It very clearly mentions in the regulations on the document that you cannot keep it at the service for more than 48 hours,

> Baggage only held within 48 hours. After 48 hours, it will be treated as unclaimed baggage.

Keeping this in mind, the $12 fee is applicable when you store your luggage for 24-48 hours, after which it will be deemed as unclaimed baggage and they cannot guarantee its safety.

On a side note, some obscure Trip Adviser users do claim that they have used it for longer durations such as 2 to 3 weeks.

A good idea also might be to call the international airport services, It's quite likely that you will be able to find someone who speaks English. This [website](http://vietnamairport.vn/page/149/cang-hang-khong-san-bay/cang-hang-khong-quoc-te-tan-son-nhat) (in Vietnamese, but Google Translate works!) mentions several numbers for the airport services.

Comment: Oh right good point! I thought it meant 48 hours after the duration you paid for. I have read indeed several people saying they left it there for weeks, so that's probably what confused me. I'll store it at a hotel then :(

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Yeah, sorry about that! :( But a hotel would be a much *safer* option.

Comment: I'm back from Vietnam and I wanted to let others know: stored it at the hotel I was staying without any problem and for free!

Answer (score 4):

Where are you staying in HCMC when you first arrive and come back? If it's the same place, and it's not an absolute shithole, they'll probably be glad to hold your bags for a few weeks since you're coming back, either for free or a small charge (not US$100!).

Comment: Yes but if I can store it in a secure storage for $12 only, I'd rather go with that. Sometimes hostels or cheap hotels store luggages in a room that is open to everyone.