# Are there any luggage lockers in Ho Chi Minh City?

Tags: luggage-storage, ho-chi-minh-city

We'll be leaving for Phnom Penh for 1 day, would like to know if there are storage lockers near HCMC and how much will be it's rate.

Comment: Like, the whole city? Or is there somewhere in particular you want to leave them? Any reason you can't leave your luggage at your present accomodation?

Comment: anywhere near backpacker street I guess... We'll we don't have any accomodations yet. But does the hostels have lockers?

Comment: Most accommodation in that area will let you leave bags in a cupboard behind reception or something. It's good business for them since you're more likely to stay at their place again if you've got something to come back for. If you want a locked locker for security, not all will offer that, so ask around.

Answer (score 5):

[There are definitely luggage lockers at Ho Chi Minh airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33768/what-is-the-cost-to-store-luggage-in-ho-chi-minh-airport-vietnam), although this might not be ideal for you. Unfortunately the internet says that there are no luggage lockers in the train station. Your best bet is likely to be asking your accomodation to store the luggage for you. They might do this for free if you promise them you will come back for another night after your trip. Others might charge you a small nominal fee for the service.

In general, don't leave valuables in your left luggage. There is no guarantee that the luggage will be locked away, and establishments usually deny all responsibility for damage and theft.

Answer (score 1):

SG Capsule at 36 le Loi, district 1. It is a hostel but also supply professional luggage storage service. You can search and make an appointment with them on their Facebook.