# What to do during a long stopover in Ho Chi Minh, Vietnam?

Tags: transit, layovers, vietnam, stopovers, sgn

I'll be traveling from Australia to India via Vietnam. The flight with VietJet has a long stopover in Vietnam, Tan Son Nhat International Airport (SGN), Ho Chi Minh City. Will there be enough time to go out and explore a bit? Also, the airline says I need to take my checked-in bags with me.

**Additional Details:**

- Indian Passport
- Aus PR
- Flight Arriving in Vietnam at 06:20, leaving Vietnam at 19:15 (*same day*)
- Stopover time: About 13 hours.

**Question:**

- What can I do during that time?
- Do I have to take my checked-in bags with me?
- If yes for the 2nd question, is there any place to store them, like a locker?

**Note:** *Other answers on the site are quite old and stuff may has changed.*

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you've got plenty of time.  In your shoes I would get a day-use hotel room near the airport, so you can also freshen up and/or take a nap, and then go explore the city.  You will need an Vietnamese e-visa, but this is quite straightforward to apply for online.

1. Downtown HCMC (Saigon) is only a few km away from SGN airport, although traffic can be *terrible*, so allow at least an hour to travel between the two plus another hour for immigration and security.  Check [Wikivoyage for things to see, do and eat](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ho_Chi_Minh_City#See).
2. VietJet is a low-cost carrier, but they do offer baggage ["Check-Thru" service](https://th.vietjetair.com/page/frequently-asked-questions) for *some* flights.  I'm not sure if Australia to India is covered though, this should have been offered when you bought your tickets?
3. [SGN has left luggage service](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33768/what-is-the-cost-to-store-luggage-in-ho-chi-minh-airport-vietnam), but your best option is to book a cheap hotel and leave your bags there.  It's hot and humid all year around in HCMC, you'll definitely want a shower after sightseeing during the day.

Comment: sounds good, is this the correct visa link ? https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/trang-chu-ttdt

Comment: @NigelFds yes indeed. As you can see the domain ends in dot gov dot vn. That's the official one.

Comment: Excellent answer – I was tempted to answer but after reading this – no need to :-)

Comment: regarding your suggestion for booking a hotel..Im unable to find any hotel that gives a room for a day with early checkin .. 2pm checkins dont make sense

Comment: @NigelFds You won't find day use rooms on regular booking websites, but most hotels do offer them, see eg. this search for Accor that pops up options like Ibis Saigon Airport: https://all.accor.com/promotions-offers/product-services/owm013408-001-vietnam-day-use.en.shtml